# What could be a good disk intensive program

Tags: unix, disk

I am looking to run some experiments which are hard disk RW intensive on my unix box.

Could you suggest me some programs which I can use for this purpose ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean testing tools as described [here](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com/2008/07/linux-filesystem-testing-tools.html)?

Comment: Yes. This is similar to what I had in mind. But I wanted something simpler. Do you have anything in mind ?